# No instance for (Num (Int -> Int)) arising from the literal `5'

Tags: haskell

I have the following function:

```
f :: (Int -> Int) -> Int
f = undefined
```

Now I want to call `f` with `5` (which is incorrect):

```
f 5
```

Obviously, this should not compile, because `5` is not a function from `Int` to `Int`.
So I would expect an error message like `Couldn't match expected type Int -> Int with Int`.

But instead I get:

```
No instance for (Num (Int -> Int)) arising from the literal `5'
In the first argument of `f', namely `5'
In the expression: f 5
In an equation for `it': it = f 5
```

Why did `Num` appear here?

Comment: What's the body of the function?

Comment: @J Does not matter. Added `undefined`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`5` is of any type in type class `Num`. These types include `Int`, `Double`, `Integer`, etc.

Functions are not in type class `Num` *by default*. Yet, a `Num` instance for functions might be added by the user, e.g. defining the sum of two functions in a pointwise fashion. In such case, the literal `5` can stand for the constant-five function.

Techncally, the literal stands for `fromInteger 5`, where the `5` is an `Integer` constant. The call `f 5` is therefore actually `f (fromInteger 5)`, which tries to convert five into `Int -> Int`. This requires an instance of `Num (Int -> Int)`.

Hence, GHC does not state in its error that `5` can not be a function (since it *could* be, if the user declared it such, providing a suitable `fromInteger`). It just states, correctly, that no `Num` instance can be found for integer functions.

Comment: I don't agree with this answer, especially on the "correctly" part. `5` is also an instance of `Show`. Why isn't it failing with: "No instance for (Show (Int -> Int))"?

Comment: @Jefffrey Right, I will add something on the impicit `fromInteger`.

Comment: @Jefffrey Because show has nothing to do with it. If `Int -> Int` is an instance of `Num`, that means that `5` can be of type `Int -> Int` (because 5 can be of any type that is an instance of `Num`). If `Int -> Int` is an instance of `Show` it doesn't mean that and therefore there's no reason why that would appear in the error message.

Comment: @Jefffrey Also "5 is also an instance of Show" - what does that mean? 5 isn't an instance of anything - it's not a type, it's a value of type `Num a => a` (and not `Show a => a` or anything else).

Comment: Regarding a Num instance for functors, there is http://hackage.haskell.org/package/applicative-numbers if you're interested in how that might look. It's actually quite handy for, e.g., expressing numerical formulae succinctly as functions.